# Why is Python not finding something on the system path?

Tags: python, linux, path

I have compiled yajl in a Linux container, which puts the compiled files in `/usr/local/lib`. I've also added this folder to the system path, so I think I should be able to reference the compiled `libyajl.so` file without specifying the full path to the file. But when I try to `pip install yajl-py` it fails, and its failing when it tries to run this line of code:

```
cdll.LoadLibrary('libyajl.so')
```

I am getting the error:

> OSError: libyajl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

To confirm I have things set up correctly I print the path:

```
import os
print(os.environ["PATH"])
```

And I get:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/lib

And to confirm the `LoadLibrary` function would work if the file was found I run:

```
from ctypes import cdll
cdll.LoadLibrary('/usr/local/lib/libyajl.so')
```

And I get the expected:

> <CDLL '/usr/local/lib/libyajl.so', handle 560efac0f110 at 0x7f61ded49ed0>

I'm a bit lost on what is going wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Explanation

The short answer because you're on a Linux distribution - rebuild your `/etc/ld.so.cache` with...

```
sudo ldconfig
```

And then try your code that uses `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` again, because libraries in `/usr/local/lib` are normally indexed and discoverable by `ctypes`.

---

### Longer Explanation

Fundamentally, `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` uses the system call [`dlopen()`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/dlopen.3.en.html), which will attempt to find libraries in the following order:

> 1. (ELF only) If the calling object (i.e., the shared library or executable from which dlopen() is called) contains a DT_RPATH tag, and
>    does not contain a DT_RUNPATH tag, then the directories listed in the
>    DT_RPATH tag are searched.
> 2. If, at the time that the program was started, the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH was defined to contain a colon-separated list
>    of directories, then these are searched. (As a security measure, this
>    variable is ignored for set-user-ID and set-group-ID programs.) o
> 3. (ELF only) If the calling object contains a DT_RUNPATH tag, then the directories listed in that tag are searched. o
> 4. The cache file /etc/ld.so.cache (maintained by ldconfig(8)) is checked to see whether it contains an entry for filename. o
> 5. The directories /lib and /usr/lib are searched (in that order).

So you can see that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is what would be searched, and not `PATH`.

**However**, your problem is probably not that you didn't have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` configured, because `dlopen` also looks in `/etc/ld.so.cache`, which is a special file that is a cache of known shared objects on the system, and on any typical Linux distribution I know of, shared libraries in `/usr/local/lib` are included in this cache.

And how this cache is rebuilt is via the tool `ldconfig`, which is (usually) configured with the file `/etc/ld.so.conf`. On my test machine (a pristine Debian Linux install), the `/etc/ld.so.conf` looks like this:

```
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
```

So you can see that the `ld.so.cache` will be compiled from libraries in this directory.

So, let me demonstrate what happens on a pristine Linux install:

```
# docker run -it debian

apt update && apt install cmake git python3 python3-pip
git clone https://github.com/lloyd/yajl
cd yajl
./configure && make && make install


# build stuff
...
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libyajl.so.2.1.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libyajl.so.2
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libyajl.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libyajl_s.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/yajl/yajl_parse.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/yajl/yajl_gen.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/yajl/yajl_common.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/yajl/yajl_tree.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/yajl/yajl_version.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/pkgconfig/yajl.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/json_reformat
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/json_reformat" to ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/json_verify
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/json_verify" to ""
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/yajl/build'
```

So now I have `/usr/local/lib/libyajl.so` (and a number of others), but Python doesn't find it:

```
root@11f76d842b80:~/yajl# python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libyajl.so")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libyajl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, you can now do one of two things - one is to manually set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running `python3`, like so...

```
root@11f76d842b80:~/yajl# LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib" python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libyajl.so")
<CDLL 'libyajl.so', handle 2c32ba0 at 0xffffa1699910>
```

And this lets `ctypes` find the library.

---

However, why do that when you could also just rebuild your `ld.so.cache`? This is usually rebuilt on system reboots (or other events, not sure what every distribution does), but you can also manually force it by running `ldconfig`.

So in my Debian container where `ctypes` can't find `libyajl.so` yet, I do this...

```
# you might need 'sudo ldconfig'
root@11f76d842b80:~/yajl# ldconfig

root@11f76d842b80:~/yajl# python3

Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libyajl.so")
<CDLL 'libyajl.so', handle 4040a30 at 0xffffa0d24ee0>
```

And now everything's right and `libyajl.so` has been indexed.

Comment: Now everything IS right! Thanks for this great answer. Running `ldconfig` fixed my issue and I agree that doing this is a cleaner solution than modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `PATH` is only used to find executables, not libraries.

To specify additional search paths for libraries, use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: This is good to know, but the accepted answer is more complete and elegant for my specific situation.